# replace text sequences in stream without lua?

Tags: itemize, markdown, bullets

I have been using the wonderful markdown package from vitek novotny, but sometimes it is overkill and lualatex is slower than pdflatex, too.   yet I do miss one feature from markdown even in my simple latex documents especially in the early authoring stages where I am still trying to piece together my logic flow:

I would love the two regex strings `\n\*\s` and `\n\s+\-\s` to be replaced by strings that I could specify (`\noindent\rule{0pt}{20pt}$bullet$` and `\hspace{4em}\rule{0pt}{16pt}$\>$`).  I don't start normal paragraphs this way, so this would rarely trip me up; and if it ever did, it would show immediately and I could escape it, or it would go away as I replace my points with text anyway.

Having this on-the-fly-replace in the normal latex byte stream would also mean that I would not have to write `\begin{markdown}\n\* ...\end{markdown}` for this simple task.  (shell scripts are not acceptable, either, because I use overleaf.)

Is there a quick-and-dirty way to accomplish this?

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This revised answer responds to a comment from the OP, indicating my original answer misinterpreted the question (since it got several upvotes, I include it later in the answer).

Because of the way TeX absorbs end-of-lines and subsequent leading spaces, I would not be able to detect leading spaces on lines without attempting additional magic (perhaps with `\obeyspaces` and/or `\endlinechar`).  Thus, what I am left with is detecting either an initial `*` or `-` following a `\par` (regardless of leading spaces or not).

I can convert those into bullets and indented levels using `tokcycle`.  Merely invoke `\tokencyclexpress\par` to commence the intercept/replacements and `\endtokencyclexpress` to terminate the intercept/replacements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newif\ifstardashcheck
\Characterdirective{%
  \tctestifcon{\ifstardashcheck}
    {\tctestifx{*#1}%
      {\addcytoks{\noindent$\bullet$}}%
      {\tctestifx{-#1}
          {\addcytoks{\noindent\hspace{20pt}$>$}}%
          {\addcytoks{#1}}%
      }%
    }%
    {\addcytoks{#1}}%
  \stardashcheckfalse
}
\Macrodirective{\tctestifx{\par#1}{\stardashchecktrue
  \addcytoks{#1}}{\stardashcheckfalse\addcytoks{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress\par%
* bullet test 1

 * bullet test 2

- indent test 1

 - indent test 2

* Bullet test 3

Normal text
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (misunderstanding OP intent)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\s\relax
\def\compA{\*}
\def\compB{+\-\s}
\def\n#1\s{%
 \def\tmp{#1}%
 \ifx\compA\tmp
  \def\next{\noindent\rule{0pt}{20pt}$\bullet$ }%
 \else
   \ifx\relax#1\relax
     \def\next{\nn}%
   \else
     \def\next{[\detokenize{\n#1\s}] }%
   \fi
 \fi
 \next
}
\def\nn#1#2#3{\def\tmp{#1#2#3}%
 \ifx\compB\tmp
   \def\next{\hspace{4em}\rule{0pt}{16pt}$>$ }%
 \else
   \def\next{[\detokenize{\n\s#1#2#3}] }%
 \fi
 \next
}
\begin{document}
Testing

\n\*\s First type.

\n\s+\-\s 2nd type.

Improperly formed 

\n123\s and 

\n\s+-=.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: my escaped characters were for a regular expression.  \n was a newline, \s was for a space character (tab or space), '+' was mean to indicate one or more.  is it possible to trigger only on 'newline star space' instead?

Comment: @ivoWelch By "trigger", do you mean make a substitution for that string, and just echo everything else literally?

Comment: @ivoWelch Also, do I understand you to mean interpret `\n` as a newline?  In LaTeX, would you want that to mean a `\par`, or literally a newline in the input stream, which LaTeX interprets as a space??

Comment: I indeed meant a substitution for these three characters in the stream.  by '\n', a paragraph break (i.e., two consecutive newlines in the input stream) would make more sense.  so, any new paragraph that starts with a `*` should become a bulleted paragraph, any paragraph that starts with a space followed by a '-' should become an indented '2nd-type' .

Comment: @ivoWelch Let me consider this. I think I can do this; it would have been a lot harder if it had to trigger on a single newline, rather than a par (double newline).

Comment: single line is more than good enough.  david's solution will also work for me, so if it is difficult, don't spend much time on it.  this is sugar, not carbs.

Comment: @ivoWelch Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 4):

> shell scripts are not acceptable, either, because I use overleaf.)

that seemed like a challenge so here is the * at start of line -> bullet replacement implemented in perl running on overleaf

[image]

The project just has two files

tex source with `*` at start of line

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

* xxx
* zzz
\end{document}
```

and a `latexmkrc` file specifying a regex replace before tex runs (`\`  written as `^^5c` to avoid working out how many `\\\\`  you need to quote `\` through the various phases.

```
$pdflatex="perl -pi -e  's/^ *[*]/^^5cpar^^5ctextbullet~/' %S; pdflatex %S"
```

Comment: wow!!!  I thought overleaf was completely sandboxed in.  I think I just learned that I can preprocess with shell and perl scripts, which gives me a whole new toolbox of flexibility.